# Increase ListBox Item height in vb6.0

Tags: vb6

I tried to bind the customer name in a list box view but the space between the item between the  row height is not much spacier. I don't know how to increase the item row height.So please any one help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Const LB_SETITEMHEIGHT = &H1A0
Const CB_SETITEMHEIGHT = &H153

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _ 
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _ 
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _ 
    ByVal wParam As Long, _ 
    lParam As Any _ 
) As Long

Sub SetListItemHeight(oCtrl As Control, ByVal lngHeight As Long)
    Dim lngMsg As Long
    If TypeOf oCtrl Is ListBox Then
        lngMsg = LB_SETITEMHEIGHT
    ElseIf TypeOf oCtrl Is ComboBox Then
        lngMsg = CB_SETITEMHEIGHT
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    SendMessage oCtrl.hWnd, lngMsg, 0, Byval CLng(lngHeight And &HFFFF&)
    oCtrl.Refresh
End Sub
```